# Solution to infinite particle creation in EM by classical sources

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In this question: [Peskin and Schroeder "Particle Creation by a Classical Source"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/86046/peskin-and-schroeder-particle-creation-by-a-classical-source)
particle creation by a classical source is discussed. Doesn't this mean that a static constant source would create infinite energy? I heard that QFT solves this problem by quantizing the source as well. How does this work?

Answer (score 0):

A classical charge $|Q|\gg e$ (source) is neutralized gradually by the oppostely charged particles of the created pairs. So the number of pairs created is less than $|Q/e|$.

Comment: so by created pairs you mean virual electron-positron pairs created by vacuum polarization?

Comment: I mean exactly what Peskin and Schroeder mean. And created pairs are not virtual, but real.